# opening a georefrenced image in IDL in ENVI

Tags: georeferencing, envi, idl

I am working with idl in envi,I want to use `ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES` in case of finding pixel value of specified point,for this porpuse I have lat and long data of my point but I need to open image in IDL as a georefrenced image
I noticed that image that is opened using `ENVI_OPEN_FILE` is not georefrenced,But if I open the same image using ENVI GUI it is georefrenced. So I think the problem is with opening image with its georefrenced data.

How do I open an georeferenced image in IDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ENVI_OPEN_FILE can open a georeferenced image. You should use ENVI_GET_MAP_INFO function to get the map information. You can see this [webpage](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/ENVI_GET_MAP_INFO.html)

Comment: Dear @JZH thank you for your help.So you mean after oppening file using ENVI_OPEN_FILE I call that function and It will fix the location of pixels base on lat and long?

Comment: ENVI_GET_MAP_INFO can get the map info through the same fid opened by ENVI_OPEN_FILE. But if you want to get the lat and long of a pixel, use ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES.

Comment: In fact I have a lat and long and I want to get their DN value on picture using IDL,SO I tried to use ENVI-CONVERT-FILE-CORDINATE but It gives me wrong data(I think it is because of not openning file as a georefrence image)..So what I shoould do?I must first open File using ENVI-OPEN_FILE Then using ENVI_GET_MAP_INFO get map info and then I use ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES to get DN values?

Comment: 1, use ENVI_OPEN_FILE to open the georeferenced image (in this case, the map info is already prepared);2,use ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES with inputs of lat and lon to get the right pixel coordinate (make sure that the image is geographical projection to match the lat and lon)

Comment: Thank you for your help.I used this code:`ENVI> ENVI_OPEN_FILE,'E:\Subset_BIP.hdr', R_FID=FID, NO_REALIZE=1
ENVI> ENVI_OPEN_FILE,'E:\MASTER\Payan_Name\DataSer\Output\162\0730\1-1Georefrence_BIP\Subset_BIP.hdr', R_FID=FID, NO_REALIZE=1
ENVI> ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES,FID,xf,yf,Xloc,Yloc
ENVI> Yloc=48.742834
ENVI> Xloc=31.345074
ENVI> ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES,FID,xf,yf,Xloc,Yloc
ENVI> xf
       54.553658073699950
ENVI> yf
       3614.6857571678161
ENVI> ` but I think the result is not right,Does it must be a location of pixel?an integer number?

Comment: I found that the projection info for my image is set to `'PROJCS["UTM_Zone_39N",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHE'...` where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can You also help me with this error while using `ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES,FID,Xloc,Yloc,xf1,yf1`I can not find out what is this about
`% Variable is undefined: XMLOC.`..Thank you very much

Comment: xf = 54.553658073699950 and yf=3614.6857571678161 are correct when xf and yf are not beyond the numbers of samples and lines of your image. You can convert the float number to the integer number and then get the pixel value through data[xf,yf].

Comment: Dear @JZH thank you for your help,But I have also problem with it.Here is a code that i used.`ENVI> data=REVERSE(data,2)
ENVI> ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES,data,x,y,31.35112761,48.73434725
ENVI> data[x,y]
       144.96194
ENVI> x
       31.351128
ENVI> y
       48.734348` as you see I used the way you said but now the result which I get is deffrent than what I get from Envi itself,I get dn in envi `Disp #1 (1273,1512) Scrn: R:112 G:112 B:112
Projection: UTM, Zone 39 North
Map: 284477.69E,3470734.50N Meters
LL : 31°21'4.06"N, 48°44'3.65"E
Data: 115.274269` Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had said that the projection of the image should be geographic projection when you use lat and lon in ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES. But the projection of your image is UTM actually. Therefore, you should convert the lat and lon to UTM and then use them in ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES.

Comment: thank you for your help..I'll try to change points projections..thank you

Comment: I found that when I use .Distinct() it returns empty.but I want distinct in the query,,Can you help me found my mistake?thanks